# Emit event vuejs 3 and quasar

Tags: vue.js, quasar

How to update this code to start calling the onTabChange method. Emitting the event does not work, the tabs were using the @input method which is currently not triggering anything, it won't display console.log, only when I replace this @input with @click, but then I get pointer event object, not the tab clicked.

```
<!-- Tabs -->
<div v-if="tabs" class="page-toolbar_tabs">
  <q-tabs
    no-caps
    align="left"
    narrow-indicator
    indicator-color="white"
    class="text-white"
    @input="onTabChange"
  >
    <q-route-tab
      v-for="(tab, index) in tabs"
      :key="index"
      :to="tab.path"
      :name="tab.name"
      :label="$t(tab.label)"
      :ripple="false"
      exact
    />
  </q-tabs>
```

and in script I have method:

```
methods: {
    onTabChange (tab) {
      console.log("this is not called")
      this.$emit('onTabChange', tab)
    }
  }
```

How to make this onTabChange pass the current tab title?

Answer (score 1):

For the second solution, you can use "@update:model-value" event on q-tab for detect current tab changing.

Answer (score 0):

Ok I have solved this by adding the click event on:

```
    <q-route-tab
      v-for="(tab, index) in tabs"
      :key="index"
      :to="tab.path"
      :name="tab.name"
      :label="$t(tab.label)"
      :ripple="false"
      exact
      @click="onTabClick(tab)"
    />
```

and then emit the event in a method:

```
methods: {
    onTabClick (tab) {
      console.log("this is now called", tab.name)
      this.$emit('onTabChange', tab.name)
    }
  }
```